# Using XSLT to separate XML file but can't get cross tag's value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file as below

```
<Season>
<Activitys>
    <Activity>
        <No>A001</No>
        <Date>2020/1/1</Date>
    </Activity>
    <Activity>
        <No>A002</No>
        <Date>2020/2/1</Date>
    </Activity>
</Activitys>

<Staffs>
    <Staff>
        <Name>Tom</Name>
        <AssignedActivity>A001</AssignedActivity>
    </Staff>
    <Staff>
        <Name>Jason</Name>
        <AssignedActivity>A002</AssignedActivity>       
    </Staff>  
</Staffs>  

<Notice>description</Notice></Season>
```

And want to transform it to 2 XML activity files, each of them will show the corresponding activity`<No>`, `<AssignedStaff>` and `<Notice>` information.

```
<Activity>
<No>A001</No>
<Date>2020/1/1</Date>
<AssignedStaff>Tom</AssignedStaff>
<Notice>description</Notice></Activity>
```

Now, I'm using below XSLT that can generate to 2 files and get activity information. But don't know how to get the assigned staff and notice tag value. I tried to use apply-template but still can't get the way. Could someone provide any ideas? Thanks a lot.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Season/Activitys/Activity">
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('output1/',No,'.xml')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />         
        <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml"> 
            <Activity>
                <No>
                    <xsl:value-of select="No"/>
                </No>
                <Date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
                </Date>
            </Activity>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the Notice you simply want `<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Season/Description"/>`.

For the reference value declare a key `<xsl:key name="staff-act" match="Staff" use="AssignedActivity"/>` and use it inside of your `for-each` with

```
<AssignedStaff><xsl:value-of select="key('staff-act', No)/Name"/></AssignedStaff>
```

Comment: Assuming there can be more than one staff assigned to an activity, I would suggest `<xsl:for-each select="key('staff', No)">
                 <AssignedStaff>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                 </AssignedStaff>
                </xsl:for-each>`.